# urandom_range(), urandom(), random() in verilog

Tags: random, verilog

I am confused between these three functions and I was wondering for some explanation. If I set the range how do I make the range exclusive or inclusive? Are the ranges inclusive or exclusive if I don't specify the range?

Comment: `$urandom_range()` and `$urandom()` are from SystemVerilog [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf). Verilog is its predecessor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In addition to the answer from @dave_59, there are other important differences:

i) `$random` returns a signed 32-bit integer; `$urandom` and `$urandom_range` return unsigned 32-bit integers.

ii) The random number generator for `$random` is specified in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf). With the same seed you will get exactly the same sequence of random numbers in any SystemVerilog simulator. That is not the case for `$urandom` and `$urandom_range`, where the design of the random number generator is up to the EDA vendor.

iii) Each thread has its own random number generator for `$urandom` and `$urandom_range`, whereas there is only one random number generator for `$random` shared between all threads (ie only one for the entire simulation). This is really important, because having separate random number generators for each thread helps you simulation improve a property called *random stability*. Suppose you are using a random number generator to generate random stimulus. Suppose you find a bug and fix it. This could easily change the order in which threads (ie `initial` and `always` blocks) are executed. If that change changed the order in which random numbers were generated then you would never know whether the bug had gone away because you'd fixed it or because the stimulus has changed. If you have a random number generator for each thread then your testbench is far less vulnerable to such an effect - you can be far more sure that the bug has disappeared because you fixed it. That property is called *random stability*.

So, As @dave_59 says, you should only be using `$urandom` and `$urandom_range`.

Comment: @Matthew Taylor- but if there is an issue with some number you wouldn't know the seed (in case of    $urandom and     $urandom_rang), so it will be diificult to repreduce the bug.

Answer (score 7):

You should only be using `$urandom` and `$urandom_range`. These two functions provide better quality random numbers and better seed initialization and stability than `$random`. The range specified by $urandom_range is always inclusive.

Although `$random` generates the exact same sequence of random numbers for each call, it is extremely difficult to keep the same call ordering as soon as any change is made to the design or testbench. Even more difficult when multiple threads are concurrently generating random numbers.

Answer (score -1):

"If I set the range how do I make the range exclusive or inclusive?"

According to IEEE 1800-2017, `$urandom_range(max, min)` specifies a range that is inclusive at both ends of the range.

Additionally: both `$urandom_range(0, 3)` and `$urandom_range(3, 0)` will return a random number between 0 and 3, inclusive.