# Instance specific $urandom in system-verilog

Tags: system-verilog

In system verilog $urandom uses the +ntb_random_seed and so reproducing the issue becomes easier. But I want to use different sequences for each instance. if all the instances of a module, having the same random value, it does not serve the purpose.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Kannan

Answer (score -1):

If you use `$urandom` the sequence generated by each module instance will be completely independent of each other. (This will not be the case for `$random`). See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698091/urandom-range-urandom-random-in-verilog/36711593#36711593) and have a play with [this example on EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4pFY): if you change the delays on the clock generator, you will see that the `urandom` module instances are completely independent of each other, whereas the `random` module instances are not.